# Why Drone reports no space left on device when perfoming build

Tags: docker, drone.io

Last week I installed the latest Drone image on a new CentOS 8 EC2 server with 100 G of storage. Currently, there is 96 GB of storage available. I have tried to build from two repositories that work fine on older Drone running on Centos 7.9.2009, but get errors like this on the new Drone installation:

`Error response from daemon: create drone-VL3XmvG5Dp3cEAh40CnF: error while creating volume root path '/var/lib/docker/volumes/drone-VL3XmvG5Dp3cEAh40CnF': mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/drone-VL3XmvG5Dp3cEAh40CnF: no space left on device`

What would cause this mkdir error when I have ample available storage?

Comment: Is there 96GB available in `/var/lib/docker`? It's possible this (or `/var`) is configured as a separate filesystem. Take a look at the output of `df -h /var/lib/docker`.

Comment: It looks like /var/lib/docker has 96G available

```df -h /var/lib/docker
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  100G  4.9G   96G   5% /```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem.  I have both a internal and internet-facing ALB for Drone and I only modified the targets of the internal ALB and forgot to modify the targets of the internet-facing ALB.  Once all Target Groups were using the new Drone server, instead of the old Drone server then my problem was fixed.